# How to update smart detection settings alerts through powershell scripts

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights

Want to update Smart detection setting alerts provided under Azure application insights using powershell cmdlets.

I want to update Smart detection setting alerts provided under Azure application insights using powershell cmdlets, following is a scenario which i want to accomplish.

Scenario: I want to update Failure Anomalies alert and register my emailid under additional email recipients and want to disable the default mail to subscription owner configuration.

Is there any way above mentioned scenario can be accomplished using powershell cmdlets?

Comment: You are asking folks to write code for you, since you are not showing any. That's not really the mission here: What have you searched for? What code have you tried? Have you installed the needed Azure module(s)? Why have you not already reviewed the help / examples in the Azure module(s)? This sort of use case is documented in in the MS Azure tech guidance docs. There are modules on the MS poershellgallery.com, that can be used for Azure scenarios.

Comment: Hello, if the answer below works for you, please help mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Here is a solution and assume your have [azure powershell az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.3.0#install-the-azure-powershell-module-1) installed(it's ok if you're using powershell azureRM module, but you need to just change the cmdlet respectively):

```
#the -Name parameter is the Failure Anomalies alert name you see in azure portal, like "Failure Anomalies - your_app_insights_name"
$alets_all = Get-AzAlertRule -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Name "xxx"
$a = $alets_all[0]
$AppIns = "xxx" #the application insights name
$ResourceGroup = "xxxx"
$SubscriptionId ="xxxx"
$Location =$a.Location
$MetricName =$a.Condition.DataSource.MetricName
$action=New-AzAlertRuleEmail -CustomEmail "abc@gmail.com; xyz@microsoft.com"
$action.SendToServiceOwners=$false
Add-AzMetricAlertRule -Name "Failure Anomalies - $AppIns" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -TargetResourceId "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/$AppIns" -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 0 -WindowSize 01:00:00 -Location $Location -TimeAggregationOperator Total -Action $action -MetricName $MetricName
```

it works well at my side, and test result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Yang for help.

Comment: @r_99, I have found a solution, and works fine. Please refer to the updated answer.  And seams that the feedback I mentioned before does not update, sorry for the that.

Comment: Hi @IvanYang, I am unable to query the `Failure Anomalies - <AppIns>` back after I create them. Does your `Get-AzAlertRule -ResourceGroupName 
xxx"` query still work in your environment? i.e. I am wondering if there is an Azure bug that has been introduced since February when you provided your answer.

Comment: @Colin, I'll take a look when I'm back to company, next monday:)

Comment: @Colin, maybe your're right, I try it now, but no result returns :(

Comment: Thanks @IvanYang for confirming. I’ve opened a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: @Colin, if any feedback of this cmdlet, could you please update this thread with that info? Thanks.